# how to change mysqldump output styles?

Tags: mysql

Extended INSERTs

```
INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (1),(2);
```

Extended INSERTs write data all in one line, the result is very hard to read.

I want like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES
(1),
(2);
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to use --skip-extended-insert.

This will give you:

```
 INSERT INTO table (id) values (1);
 INSERT INTO table (id) values (2);
```

If you want to process the output, the data all appears at the same position in the line (depending on the number of columns and the lengths of their names) and text with lots of repeats like this will compres well for sending over the wire.

Comment: sorry, I don't want this, this solution is not efficient.

Comment: :-) In what sense is this not efficient? On the one hand, the --skip-extended-insert is a very well known option of mysqldump and the output it gives you is very regular (column name lengths do not change) and using a script to translate the mysqldump output to the exact output you want is trivial. If you find some obscure feature of MySQL, or some more complex solution, that gives you exactly the output you want, that is going to be less efficient in the long run. Especially when you forget how it works or have to re-build it to do something slightly different.